# Can an android application(client) communicate with a java web server using sockets?

Tags: java, android, sockets, webserver

I need an android application to communicate with a java web server using sockets, but can't seem to find any information regarding this.  I have only been able to find information about java to java and android to android.

Comment: It absolutely has to be using sockets? or can it be done using HTTP?

Comment: HTTP is a protocol, a socket is a transport.  You have to use a socket to use HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

When I first tried doing this, I used the basic knock example taken from [Lesson: All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html), most likely written before the android OS existed, and adapted the server side to run on an android. That way I didn't have to make an user interface and could just focus on the communication. The code is here: [EchoClient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoClient.java), [KnockKnockServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockServer.java), and [KnockKnockClient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockProtocol.java).

The problems I initially ran into included:

- Making sure that both sides knew which port to use.
- Making sure I had set the permissions on the Android side to use the internet.
- Making sure the client knew the ip of the server.

I posted my version of this code [here](https://povinelli.eece.mu.edu/twiki/bin/view/Main/EmbeddedSystems). It worked one year, and then I had to fiddle with it again when I used it for my class this year. My students got it working, though. You'll get a security flag when you go to the site, since I don't want to pay for an officially registered certificate, but that is a rant for another day :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) is an example how to use sockets in Android. With web server you should do the same. If you want to work with http protocol here is another [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-networking/).

Comment: See [Are answers that just contain a link elsewhere really "good answers"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259)

Comment: Thanks, now I'll know about this and I'll avoid this in the future.